# Receiving "You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard'" Errors during Runtime Compilation

Tags: c#, .net-core, compiler-errors, compilation, roslyn

Using C# runtime compilation (**Roslyn**), I am receiving many errors stating I have not added references to **netstandard** despite compiling under the context of a **netcoreapp**.

Errors appear with the following format:

> The type 'XXX' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0...

The code processing resulting in this can be distilled into the following snippet:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace Compiler
{
    public static class Compiler
    {
        public static Assembly CompileAssembly(string code, bool compileAsExecutable = false)
        {
            var outputKind = compileAsExecutable ? OutputKind.ConsoleApplication : OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary;
            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
            var syntaxTrees = new[] {syntaxTree};
            var systemAssemblyReference = GetMetadataReference<object>();
            var patchBandAssemblyReference = GetMetadataReference<AssemblyTargetedPatchBandAttribute>();
            var references = new[] {systemAssemblyReference, patchBandAssemblyReference};
            var cSharpCompilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(outputKind);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(@"Countdown", syntaxTrees, references, cSharpCompilationOptions);

            using (var assemblyStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var emitResult = compilation.Emit(assemblyStream);

                if (emitResult.Success)
                {
                    var assemblyBytes = assemblyStream.ToArray();

                    return Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
                }

                var errors = emitResult
                    .Diagnostics
                    .Select(diagnostic => diagnostic.GetMessage())
                    .Select(message => new Exception(message));

                throw new AggregateException(errors);
            }
        }

        private static string GetAssemblyLocation<T>()
        {
            var typeOfT = typeof(T);

            return typeOfT.Assembly.Location;
        }

        private static PortableExecutableReference GetMetadataReference<T>()
        {
            var assemblyLocation = GetAssemblyLocation<T>();

            return MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assemblyLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add a reference to the **netstandard.dll**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace Compiler
{
    public static class Compiler
    {
        public static Assembly CompileAssembly(string code, bool compileAsExecutable = false)
        {
            var outputKind = compileAsExecutable ? OutputKind.ConsoleApplication : OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary;
            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
            var syntaxTrees = new[] {syntaxTree};

            // Requested the reference be fetched
            var runtimeSpecificReference = GetRuntimeSpecificReference();
            var systemAssemblyReference = GetMetadataReference<object>();
            var patchBandAssemblyReference = GetMetadataReference<AssemblyTargetedPatchBandAttribute>();

            // Added the reference to the value here
            var references = new[] {runtimeSpecificReference, systemAssemblyReference, patchBandAssemblyReference};

            var cSharpCompilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(outputKind);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(@"Countdown", syntaxTrees, references, cSharpCompilationOptions);

            using (var assemblyStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var emitResult = compilation.Emit(assemblyStream);

                if (emitResult.Success)
                {
                    var assemblyBytes = assemblyStream.ToArray();

                    return Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
                }

                var errors = emitResult
                    .Diagnostics
                    .Select(diagnostic => diagnostic.GetMessage())
                    .Select(message => new Exception(message));

                throw new AggregateException(errors);
            }
        }

        private static string GetAssemblyLocation<T>()
        {
            var typeOfT = typeof(T);

            return typeOfT.Assembly.Location;
        }

        private static PortableExecutableReference GetMetadataReference<T>()
        {
            var assemblyLocation = GetAssemblyLocation<T>();

            return MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assemblyLocation);
        }

        // This function was needed
        private static PortableExecutableReference GetRuntimeSpecificReference()
        {
            var assemblyLocation = GetAssemblyLocation<object>();
            var runtimeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
            var libraryPath = Path.Join(runtimeDirectory, @"netstandard.dll");

            return MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(libraryPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A SO user must dig pretty deep to find where you "hid" the solution this problem. Maybe your solution would be more helpful if you made it obvious what you changed to get your code to work

Comment: I added code comments to indicate the changes. Any advice for further highlighting the delta in the code snippet?